# Window snapping in debian?

Tags: debian, window-manager, window

I haven't been able to find anything using Google, but I'd like to use a window snap feature in Debian Jessie. Is there anything like this available?

Alternatively, if I could start certain programs by specifying the size of their window, such as browsers like Firefox or Chrome, that would also serve my purpose.

Comment: Use a tiling window manager...

Comment: What do you mean by “window snap feature”? There are lots of features that could be called this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think with "snap window" you mean the window uses left/right/upper/lower half of screen, or one quarter of it, if moving it to one border or corner of screen.

Kwin (part of KDE) has this feature, xfwm4 (part of Xfce)(since 4.10 or 4.12, I'm not sure), too. (Has to be configured). Some other window managers may support it, too.

You did not tell your desktop in your question. I don't know if Gnome (as default of debian jessie) supports this feature. Gnome cannot change its window manager, Xfce and LXDE can use other than their default.

Comment: Would you please provide indications as how to enable this feature from the desktop environment, perhaps having in mind vanilla users? Thx

Comment: @XavierStuvw My system is in German, not sure how the options are called in english translations. I try to ranslate: Xfce: "Settings -> Finetuning Window Manager -> Accessability -> Automatically raster windows if moving them to screen edge". KDE/KWin: IIRC enabled per default. Currently not installed on my system.